# The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used

Tags: angular, azure, redirect, single-sign-on

While redirecting after SSO Authentication to Angular web app(Azure web app),I'm getting error as "**The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this error might occur. It is possible that a method you are using is not allowed - for example, if the client makes an HTTP request by sending the POST method to a page that is not configured to handle it. You may have an API which needs some argument but you are not passing those arguments from your Angular.

You can refer to several [threads](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b49f71d4-b0d4-473f-95a1-6f06ee873311/405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-for-the-verb-propfind?forum=vstswebtest) on MSDN and Stackoverflow where others have faced the same issue.

Here are some troubleshooting steps from the [official Microsoft guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942051/error-message-when-a-user-visits-a-website-that-is-hosted-on-a-server).

Cause 1: This problem occurs because the client makes an HTTP request by using an HTTP method that does not comply with the HTTP specifications.

Resolution 1:

Make sure that the client sends a request that contains a valid HTTP method. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, type Notepad in the Start Search box, right-click Notepad, and then click Run as administrator.
   Note: If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or provide confirmation.
2. On the File menu, click Open. In the File name box, type `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config`, and then click Open.
3. In the ApplicationHost.config file, locate the  tag.
4. Make sure that all the handlers use valid HTTP methods.
5. Save the ApplicationHost.config file.

Cause 2: This problem occurs because a client makes an HTTP request by sending the POST method to a page that is configured to be handled by the StaticFile handler. For example, a client sends the POST method to a static HTML page. However, pages that are configured for the StaticFile handler do not support the POST method.

Resolution 2:

Send the POST request to a page that is configured to be handled by a handler other than the StaticFile handler (for example, the ASPClassic handler). Or, change the request that is being handled by the StaticFile handler so that it is a GET request instead of a POST request.

Comment: Marilee Turscak- I'm setting a Call back url for SSO that is Angular call back url. MicrosoftSSO Provider will reply back to the url as SAML Response But I'm Getting error as above.But for the Backend application like Web api  it's not throwing any error as above.

Comment: Turscak- It's occuring in Azure web app.@Marilee Turscak - MSFT