# Why StaticFile handler running instead of Custom handler

Tags: iis-10, staticfilehandler

I am migrating a legacy web application to iis 10. Site is mostly written in classic asp and asp code is running fine for files with .asp extension. However, there are some pages in the site are saved with the .uasp extension which is throwing the error:

[image]

To resolve this, I added a handler mapping in the iis

[image]

But iis is still throwing the same error from the "StaticFile" handler. My question is why my handler is not recognized? Any suggestion/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Open `applicationHost.config` and find all lines that are `.asp` related. Then replicate them for `.uasp`. That's simpler than using IIS Manager, and the elements will be in the right order too.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `HTTP VERB`, so we should focus on that angle.  Here is an article on stackoverflow talking about this error:

[The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944177/the-page-you-are-looking-for-cannot-be-displayed-because-an-invalid-method-http)

If you read that link, I think its the 2nd option situation.  You can POST or GET data, and you use `POST` with a form, and `GET` from a url string.  You are using the later with a url string like showfile.uasp?name=bob , so check your code and make sure that GET is used and not POST.